# Entity Framework 5, Invalid column name error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am using entity framework 5. I have a scenario of parent child recursive structure.For that I have written a code like below:

```
 public class Step
    {
        public Step()
        {
            this.Childs = new HashSet<Step>();
        }
    public int Id { get; set; }        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Step> Childs { get; set; }
        public virtual Step Parent { get; set; }
    }
```

I am getting **Invalid column name "Parent_Id"** Error. 
Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Are you sure this has all the relevant code? I can't see anything called `Parent_Id` there. Alternatively, is `Parent` supposed to be (or to be mapped against) an actual table column `parent`? Have you checked that this mapping is correct?

Comment: @Kjartan: Yes, this is same code.

Comment: How was the database created?

Comment: @haim770: It is database first approach.

Comment: Show your mapping then. did you make sure the `Parent_Id` column exist?

Comment: This is not clear, you say you have _written_ this code (= code-first), then you say you work database-first, which would _generate_ code. So which is it? Also, at which point do you get this exception? Please show this code as well.